# How to modify /xampp added to website url after File Transfer from localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

I have recently transferred my files from localhost to a web site. I used XAMPP to develop the files and transfer them to the web host. Everything is working fine except that /XAMPP was somehow added to the URL and has prevented access to the main web page. Any ideas on how to modify/remove this would be appreciated. Thanks!
So my webpage www.webpage.com now becomes www.webpage.com/xampp and I need to change the path to a login page from the xampp path
Thanks!

Comment: You moved files from localhost's htdocs/ directory? Or, did you moved whole inside xampp/ directory?

Comment: I transferred only the htdocs and cgi-bin files, but they were contained within C:/xampp

Comment: where did you stored the website files on localhost?
- Inside C:\xampp\htdocs ?
- Or, any sub-folder inside C:\xampp\htdocs ?

Comment: They are stored inside C:\xampp\htdocs. Not in a sub folder

Comment: Then, only move files inside htdocs/ to your webserver. Remove other uploaded files first. After this, try again accessing your application.

Comment: Thanks very much, that removed the XAMPP path....can you advise about how to add a path to the original website name that will take me directly to the login page when I type the website name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then, only move files inside htdocs/ to your webserver. Remove other
>   uploaded files first. After this, try again accessing your
>   application.

Comment: Also, as you asked in comment that you want to redirect user directly to login.php page, This can be achieved by using 
`DirectoryIndex login.php` in .htaccess file inside your webserver directory.